# Generating a customized Project file with Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

In my current requirement I would like to create a customized project which my application can load in future. The project file will be specific to my application only. It will contain all the paths of the created components as items represent unique directories. There will be loading of some other tools from my application which will also generate some files and their record is also to be maintained in my project file. This project file can be loaded also by my application.

I could use QSettings, but the problem is that the file extension of a QSettings file will be either .ini or .conf, whereas my project file extension which will be, let's say, .amu.

I can also do this using XML. But can anybody suggest some other good way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`QSettings` constructor which takes file name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings-4). Then you could use any extension of your choosing. Prototype for reference:

```
QSettings::QSettings(const QString & fileName, Format format, QObject * parent = 0);
```

Comment: But is it possible to create a file with Qsettings other than .ini .I dont think its going to work out.

Comment: @RaghawShukla I didn't test, but why do you think it's not going to work out? `QSettings settings("/mypath/myproject.amu",  QSettings::IniFormat);` should work I think.